# If $\lim \text{sup}_{n\to\infty}X_n≠\lim \text{inf}_{n\to\infty}X_n$, can we say "limit doesn't exist"?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, limsup-and-liminf

According to the definition of the limit, if $\lim \text{sup}_{n\to\infty}X_n=A$ and $\lim \text{inf}_{n\to\infty}X_n=B$  where, $A≠B$. Terminologically, can we say *"limit doesn't exist"*?

Exact meaning of my question is, for example:

Let $\phi(n)$ be a Euler totient function, then we have

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> {\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{sup} \frac{\phi (n)}{n}=1} \\
> {\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{inf} \frac{\phi (n)}{n}=0}
> \end{cases} \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{n}{\text{doesn't exist.}}$$

Do I use this statement correctly?

Comment: Do you mean that $X_n=Y_n$ is the same sequence?

Comment: @EclipseSun I'm sorry, I fixed.

Comment: In the shaded box, you have an extra $\Rightarrow$. After the first, you should have “$\lim\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$ does not exist”

Comment: $\limsup$ is the supremum of the set of points that are limits of subsequences of $X_n$; $\liminf$ is the infimum of the set of points that are limits of subsequences of $X_n$. If the set is not a singleton, then the limit does not exist; if the sup and inf of the set are different, then the set is not a singleton.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I fixed as You say. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, because whan the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ of a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ exists, then$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions of $\limsup_n$ is the supremum of the partial limits, and $\liminf_n$ is the same just with infimum, if those 2 are different then there is more than one partial limit, so there is no limit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, terminologically it is correct since the limit is a number compatible with the [limit's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition). When the $\lim \text{sup}$ and $\lim \text{inf}$ are different, such a number does not exist, thus the limit does not exist.